# How to calculate number of cards' permutations in card game

Tags: combinatorics

I have trick taking based card game with 32 cards. Initially each player has 8 cards. After each trick number of cards in all players' hands are decreasing by one. I'm writing an AI Bot which knows only its own cards (8 cards), so 24 are unknown in its point of view. 
When it searches for a best move/card to play it iterates 4000 times (hard-coded number) using Monte Carlo Tree Search, and on each iteration it assigns a permutation of cards for the other 3 players (thus, I have a game with perfect information for a current iteration).
For example if P0 is Bot player, and P1, P2, P3 are the other players, then here is number of cards distribution (after every trick):

```
------------------------------------ P1 ---- P2 ---- P3 ---- NC ------
Searching a best move for Trick 1:    8       8       8 ---> 24 cards
Searching a best move for Trick 2:    7       7       7 ---> 21 cards
Searching a best move for Trick 3:    6       6       6 ---> 18 cards
....
....
Searching a best move for Trick 8:    1       1       1 ---> 3 cards
```

How to calculate number available cards permutations in order to avoid hard-coded iterations, because on Trick 8 there are just 6 permutations of 3 cards but algorithm still iterates 4000 times.

I know permutations are calculates as factorial, but the problem is more complicated because of fact that each permutation is divided on 3 groups (3 players), and cards' permutations in each player's hand must be ignored.

Examples of card distribution on Trick 6:

```
1)
Trick 6: --- P1 ---- P2 ---- P3 
           1 2 3    3 4 5   6 7 8 

2) 
Trick 6: --- P1 ---- P2 ---- P3 
           2 1 3    3 4 5   8 7 6 

3)
Trick 6: --- P1 ---- P2 ---- P3 
           1 3 2    3 5 4   6 7 8
```

1), 2) and 3) should be counted as one permutation.

Comment: Are you asking for help solving this in Wolfram *Mathematica* or shall I move your question to [Math.SE]?

Comment: Move it to Mathematics, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After $k$ turns, there are $24 - 3k$ cards left unseen distributed evenly among three players. The total number of permutations is thus $(24 - 3k)!$, but we don't care about the orderings of the $8 - k$ cards within each of the other players' hands. There are $(8-k)!$ such orderings for each of three players, and so the total number of combinations after $k$ turns is
$$\frac{(24-3k)!}{(8-k)!^3}.$$

If you don't care about the ordering of the other three players, then the number of distinct combinations so regarded is
$$\frac{(24-3k)!}{3!(8-k)!^3}.$$

In both cases, the first time number of combinations is no larger than your set search space of $4000$ is $k = 5$, when the numbers of combinations are $1680$ and $280$, respectively.